# Django counting relations for each user

Tags: sql, django, django-models

How to count how many "friends" each user has and then display it in the descending order.

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    to_friend = models.ForeignKey(User)
    from_friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner')
```

I`ve had an idea for counting relationships, but i think its not an effective way to do it.

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    user.friend_set.all().count()
```

Comment: I think you make it a bit hard with the `from_friend` and `to_friend` relations. Can you explain this kind of modelling? Why not use a Many-to-Many relation?

Comment: Because i'd like to have object for each of relations between user. But i'm not certain thats the right way to implement friends functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, it looks like a lot of queries to me here.

Apart from questioning the `Model` architecture, I would suggest you a way to do this somewhat gracefully.

`User.objects.prefetch_related('friend_set')`

You can read about this `prefetch_related` in [Django Documentation here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Now, there is one problem here. This aforementioned query may return duplicate `Friends`. The solution to this is `Prefetch`

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
query = Prefetch('friend_set', Friend.objects.distinct())
User.objects.prefetch_related(query)
```

This will actually prefetch for you all the unique `Friends` for `Users`.

Now, regarding the `Count` of `unique friends`, I think this would do -

```
from django.db.models import Count
User.objects.prefetch_related(query).annotate(number_of_friends=Count('friend'))
```

You can read more about `annotate`  [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

Answer (score 0):

It's a effective way because you can't have repeated relationships (and if you has you can use the distinct) and count will return the number of relationships. 
To order them descending you can do this:

```
query.order_by('-id_user')
```